# I need a specific kernel version. How do I get the corresponding Debian iso?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, system-installation, version, debian-installer

Say I need a Debian with Kernel `3.2.63-2+deb7u1` i686.

How do I find the corresponding Debian Version? I assume it would be Debian 7 because [this](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianWheezy) document states that Debian 7 has Kernel version 3.2. Yet, there are several iso images I can download, e.g. `debian-7.8.0-i386-netinst.iso`, `debian-7.9.0-i386-netinst.iso`, etc. How do I know which of these isos will result in a system with the exact kernel version 3.2 ***.63-2+deb7u1*** I need?

Or, maybe, is this a matter of installing the .deb corresponding to the specific version, i.e. up- or downgrading the kernel as needed?

Comment: Are you sure you need that specific a version. It's very uncommon not to be able to use later versions.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Unfortunately I need exactly this version.

Comment: You can certainly install a different version after ISO install, provided that your system boots with the installer kernel.

Comment: @pjc50 The system does boot with the installer kernel. How do I install the `3.2 .63-2+deb7u1` kernel? Creating the .deb from the source package (see 'the snapshots' link in the answer below) ?

Comment: I think you can get the binary package directly: http://snapshot.debian.org/package/linux/3.2.63-2%2Bdeb7u1/#kernel-image-3.2.0-4-686-pae-di_3.2.63-2:2b:deb7u1 although I can't remember whether udebs are installable and I don't currently have a running debian system.

Comment: (*why* do you need this specific version, anyway?)

Comment: @pjc50 I need it for an introspection tool that just works with this version.

Comment: if your introspection tool requires a specific kernel version (and can not be re-compiled to work with other kernel versions), then it is broken.  Instead of tying yourself forever to one long-obsolete kernel, you should look for alternative tools that do the same/similar job.  You should do this no matter how good or convenient or fit-for-your-purpose your current tool is - the price it demands is far too high.

Comment: @cas I got the kernel installed. One more reason to go this way was to learn how to do it. And indeed I learned a lot. I now know how to install whatever kernel version I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Wheezy changelog](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/ChangeLog) lists all the package updates in each point release. This shows that [Debian 7.7](https://lists.debian.org/debian-announce/2014/msg00008.html) was released with 3.2.63-2, while [Debian 7.8](https://lists.debian.org/debian-announce/2015/msg00000.html) was released with version 3.2.65-1. So you won't find an installer image with the exact version you're looking for.

But you can find the relevant kernel packages in [the snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/linux/3.2.63-2%2Bdeb7u1/); this will allow you to install the version you're after.

Comment: But insn't the 3.2.63-2 of Debian 7.7 exactly what I need then? What does this '**deb7u1**' mean anyway?

Comment: In 3.2.63-2+deb7u1, deb7u1 means this is the first update of 3.2.63-2 targeting Debian 7; it's not the same as 3.2.63-2. See [the corresponding patch](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/kernel/linux.git/commit/?h=wheezy-security&id=c98fed39d5c395df4e644eded1b3489b640b2c82) for details (it includes the changelog).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are isos with that kernel, but why don't you try to compile the kernel that you need. [Here's](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch08s06.html.en) a guide on how to compile a kernel for debian.

Answer (score 0):

If the regular kernel boots and supports at least the hard disk controller, you can also place the required packages on a local server, using a tool such as `reprepro` or `apt-ftparchive` to create the correct `Packages` and `Release` files, and use the installer's expert mode to add the server as an additional package source.

Because you are in expert mode, the installation process will ask which kernel package to install.